# A SELECT query is executed per each row result when using JdbcTemplace.query()

Tags: java, database, jdbc, oracle11g, acl

I realized that when I execute a simple select that returns many records using JdbcTemplace.query(), hundreds of select are being executed in the background. 
Actually one per row, which ends up being a performance issue due to the high number of records in my ACL table for some users.

```java
private final String PERMISSIONS_QUERY = "SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl WHERE acl.principal = :userId ";
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource(DAOConstants.USER_ID_KEY, userId);

List<UserPermissionRow> userPermissions = jdbcTemplate.query(PERMISSIONS_QUERY, params,
                new RowMapper<UserPermissionRow>() {
                    @Override
                    public UserPermissionRow mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        return new UserPermissionRow(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
                    }
                });
```

I looked into the P6Spy logs that displays the queries being executed. As you can see one query is executed by row (not very efficient I think).

```sql
READ
1566811816536|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10078, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816536|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10079, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816536|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10080, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816536|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10081, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816536|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10082, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816536|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10083, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816538|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10084, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816538|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10085, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816538|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10086, PERMISSION =
 READ
1566811816538|-1||resultset|SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl  WHERE acl.principal = '11582' |USER_ID = 10087, PERMISSION = READ

...
..
.
```

I wonder whether there would be a more efficient approach to retrieve this high volume of data with just one select to the DB.

I would very much appreciate some feedback.

The response time for the original approach in the question was 5726 ms.

See below the alternative approaches I tried. 
Unfortunately the overall timing did not improve.

***OPTION 1 (Statament)***

```java
Statement stmt = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(EXPERT_ACCESS_QUERY_2 + userId);
List<UserPermissionTest> list =new ArrayList<UserPermissionTest>();
    // ============= Expert Access Query RAW: 79 ms
while(rs.next()){
    UserPermissionTest e=new UserPermissionTest();
    e.setIdentity(rs.getString(1));
    e.setPermission(rs.getString(2));
    list.add(e);
}
    // ============ 5554 ms
```

***OPTION 2 (ResultSetExtractor)***

```java
List <UserPermissionTest> userPerms = jdbcTemplate.query(EXPERT_ACCESS_QUERY_2 + userId, 
    new ResultSetExtractor<List<UserPermissionTest>>(){

    @Override
    public List<UserPermissionTest> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

        List<UserPermissionTest> list =new ArrayList<UserPermissionTest>();
        while(rs.next()){
            UserPermissionTest e=new UserPermissionTest();
            e.setIdentity(rs.getString(1));
            e.setPermission(rs.getString(2));
            list.add(e);
         }
         return list;
    }
});
    //========= 5694 ms
```

Comment: *"As you can see one query is executed by row"* I can't see that. The output looks to me like the dump of multiple rows from a single query execution, that simply repeats the query on every row output. Why else would the result (USER_ID and PERMISSION) be different for the exact same query?

Comment: *"The response time for the original approach in the question was 5726 ms"* --- Perhaps you are missing an index on the `principal` column, so the query is doing a full table scan.

Comment: Have you even tried running that query directly on the database yourself?

Comment: Yes, I executed in the DB client. 
The client returns 40 rows in 0.098 seconds. Obviously the query has a total of 30544 records for this ID.

Comment: Since the query returns 30544 record for that ID, and it only shows 40 rows when running in DB client, then obviously the DB client stops after 40 and you have to scroll to see more, which means it didn't read all 30544 results, and the timing value is meaningless for comparison. Try again, but this time measure the time to get *all* the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that is because you are using a single userId in your sql script below:

```
private final String PERMISSIONS_QUERY = "SELECT acl.user_id, acl.permission FROM v_user_acls acl WHERE acl.principal = :userId ";
```

Try using IN and use the list of userID as parameter in your where condition?

I found this reference if this could help:
https://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-jdbctemplate-in-clause-example

Comment: No, it isn't that. 
The acl.principal Id does not change from one query to the next.
As you can see in the SQLs I provided, the user Id assigned to acl.principal doesn't change, it is the ID of the logged user. 
If I include the IN clause the query is executed the same number of times but just with a IN (ID) instead of = ID.

Comment: Just to clarify, I tried what you said and it is the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It seems that as reported by Andreas the logs are not really calls to the DB but rather the Result Set being logged in each iteration.
The only solution I have found to improve the performance is to work on the DB View to improve its performance. Sorry for the confusion.